# Implementation of Qt Model/View architecture - separate the files using folders?

Tags: qt, model-view

I am doing my final year project on Qt/OML mobile app project. I was required to use architecture on it and since I choose Qt, I use Model/View with delegate.

Previously I only used three-tier architecture with ASP.NET which I separate database class files (data tier), business logic files(application tier) and presentation tier files into 3 folders.

How about in Qt? Do I have to separate those model, view and delegate files? In the [example here](http://get.qt.nokia.com/developerguides/qtquicksymbian/ProgrammingQtQuick4SymbianHarmattanDevices.pdf) I saw delegates file are being separated, while the model and view are put together in one file (main.qml).

Comment: Do whatever suits the best for your project and never write a bad code!